# Swagger - Configure JSON File C#

Tags: c#, swagger

I'm on a new project at work and i have been introduced to the Swagger tool. I've updated the dependencies of the project, uploading the swagger version from 7.7 to 11.3. But now it doesn't work, because a library stop working. Any idea what the equivalent might be? I've looked and I keep looking on the internet, but I can not find anything ..

My code

```
using NSwag.CodeGeneration.SwaggerGenerators.WebApi;//This doesn't exists
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using apiplanificador.Fachadas.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Dispatcher;
using System.Reflection;
using NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp;//Trying with this

namespace apiplanificador.Fachadas
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            //Generamos el JSON a partir del código del controlador.
            ConvertirJSON();

            // Rutas de API web
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Genera el fichero JSON necesario para la documentación
        /// Hay que sustituir HomeController por el controlador creado para cada proyecto
        /// </summary>
        public static void ConvertirJSON()
        {
            var settings = new WebApiToSwaggerGeneratorSettings//this  doesn't work
            {
                DefaultUrlTemplate = "v1/{controller}/{id}",
                Title = "Api Planificador",
                Description = "Api que permite gestionar las tareas del planificador",
                Version = "v1"
            };
            var generator = new WebApiToSwaggerGenerator(settings);//This doesn't work
```

Thanks!

Comment: for webapi project, I think you can use `swashbuckle`

Comment: Thanks! i'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual name of libraries are:

```
using NSwag.SwaggerGenerators.WebApi
```

And the nuget package

```
NSwag.SwaggerGenerators.WebApi
```